# PHP file in iFrame on WordPress - where to put it

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress website, in one of the pages I have a link like this:

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="walk.php/?id=12345>link</a>
```

This link opens a lightbox with an iFrame whose contents are generated by the linked PHP file.

Where should I put the walk.php file for it to be accessible by this page? I know that I can access it if I put it the root of my wordpress installation, but I would want it included in my theme folder to be portable. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/walk.php?id=12345`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But I used get_stylesheet_directory_uri() which is the shortand for get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').
Please make your comment as an answer to the question, so I can mark it as the correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');`

```
<a class="fancybox iframe" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/walk.php?id=12345">link</a>
```